# Center point of the tilted rectangle

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to do a diagram of forces. I tilted my rectangle with the right angle as well as the vector pointing upwards. How do I make my Weight vector? I want it to point down and to start at the center point of the tilted rectangle, but i'm not getting how. Here's the code.[image]

Comment: Hi there, and welcome to TeX StackExchange! Could you please edit your question to include your code so that we can copy and paste it? That way, we can compile your diagram on our own and better help you with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### How to find the weight vector

Because you're drawing a diagram for a physics problem, we can approach this drawing the same way we would approach solving the problem.

1. Switch into the reference frame of the box. In Ti*k*Z, this means that we pretend there is no rotation. Let's let the angle *θ* be the macro `\myAngle`. The weight vector is shown below in red.

[image: A block with a vector pointing perpendicular upwards from it, and a vector pointing to the bottom right. The vector pointing to the bottom right is the weight vector, and is colored red.]

2. The weight vector has an *x*-component of *mg* sin(*θ*), and a *y*-component of −*mg* cos(*θ*). We want to use these components in our Ti*k*Z code, too. The coordinates of the center of the block are (2.25, 2.55), so this is the starting point of the weight vector. The end point is therefore `({2.25 + \mg * sin(\myAngle)}, {2.55 - \mg * cos(\myAngle)})`.
3. Finally, we switch back into the lab frame of reference, where the block sits on the incline. To do this, we apply the option `rotate around={-\myAngle:(1.5,2.1)}` onto the block, normal force vector, and weight vector.

### Resulting image

[image: A block lies on an incline of angle theta. There are two vectors illustrated on the block: the normal force, and the force of gravity. Both vectors are drawn originating from the center of mass of the block.]

### Code

I was too lazy to actually determine the weight `\mg` of the block based on the value of the normal force you provided in your code, so I'll leave it as a little exercise to the reader :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\mg{1.2}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % The triangle
  \draw[black,thick](0,0) -- (5,0) -- (0,3) -- cycle;
  
  % Drawing theta
  \draw(3.5,0) arc (180:135:1) node[midway,anchor=east,black]{$\theta$};
  
  % Calculate the rotation
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\myAngle}{atan(3/5)}
  
  % Rectangle, normal force, and gravity
  \draw[rotate around={-\myAngle:(1.5,2.1)}] (1.5,2.1) rectangle (3,3);
  \draw[rotate around={-\myAngle:(1.5,2.1)}, black, ->, thick]
    (2.25,2.55) -- (2.25,3.55);
  \draw[rotate around={-\myAngle:(1.5,2.1)}, black, ->, thick]
    (2.25,2.55) -- ({2.25 + \mg * sin(\myAngle)}, {2.55 - \mg * cos(\myAngle)});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to calculating coordinates.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,calc,quotes}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[thick]
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\rew}{1.5cm} % rectangle width
        \pgfmathsetlengthmacro{\reh}{0.9cm} % rectangle height
        \draw (0,0) coordinate (A) -- (5,0) coordinate (B) -- (0,3) coordinate (C) -- cycle;
        \pic[draw, angle radius=1.5cm, "$\theta$", angle eccentricity=1.2] {angle = C--B--A};
        \coordinate (A1) at (1.5,2.1);
        \coordinate (A2) at ($(A1)!\rew!(B)$);
        \coordinate (A3) at ($(A2)!\reh!90:(B)$);
        \coordinate (A4) at ($(A1)!\reh!90:(B)$);
        \draw (A1) -- (A2) -- (A3) -- (A4) -- cycle;
        \coordinate (M) at ($(A1)!0.5!(A2)$); % center of  A1--A2
        \coordinate (X) at ($(A1)!0.5!(A3)$); % center of rectangle
        \draw[->] (X) -- ($(X)!-1cm!(M)$);
        \draw[->,red] (X) -- ++(0,-1);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]